# How to fix Facebook App Login Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

I am new to Facebook App Developing. I am trying to use facebook login. But this error is popping up. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv45D.png) This is my code.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 require_once 'Facebook/autoload.php';
 $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '240676292969845', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => '111111111111111111111',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
  ]);

 $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

 $permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://warunaphotography.com/fb-callback.php', $permissions);

 echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($loginUrl) . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
?>
```

This is the facebook app settings.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHNt.png)
Please help me.

Comment: So, make the settings the error message is talking about. (Hint: Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field is under Products->Facebook Login. Add it, if not already present.)

Comment: How do i set it.?? @CBroe

Comment: By filling out the relevant fields in app dashboard.